# Is there a Javascript Function to reappend an html element in the order of its numerical content?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm working on application to rearrange html divs into descending order based upon their numerical content. So far I've made a function to order the numerical values upon their entry and append them to a  corresponding div. It all looked good until I realized upon each new entry, the position of the numerical content changes, but not the actual order of Divs. I would like to link the numerical content to its div and order the div, not just the numbers. Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

(Edited)
The code in which the problem is occurring is towards the bottom of the Javascript code.

HTML BELOW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Order Divs</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="point-input">
  <button id="sub-btn">Submit</button>
    <button id=order>Order Button</button>
    <button id="add-btn">Add</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript below!

```
//variables below

let orderBtn=document.getElementById("order")
console.log(orderBtn)

let addBtn=document.getElementById("add-btn")
console.log(addBtn)

const container=document.getElementById("container")
console.log(container)


let numArr=[]

let numInc=1

let numToBeRe=[]

let child=document.getElementsByClassName(`child${numInc}`)
console.log(`child${numInc}`)

let subBtn=document.getElementById("sub-btn")
console.log(subBtn)

let pointInput=document.getElementById("point-input")
console.log(pointInput)

let numbers=document.querySelector(".numbers")
console.log(numbers)



//adding an event lister to the submit button below 

subBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
let pointInput=document.getElementById("point-input")   
    console.log(pointInput.value)
        numToBeRe.push(pointInput.value) //push the input field value to an array
            console.log(numToBeRe)
//              console.log(typeof(pointInput.value))
                    pointInput=parseInt(pointInput.value)
                    console.log(pointInput)
                    
                        console.log(numToBeRe)
                            numToBeRe.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
                                console.log(numToBeRe)

                                    
                                        


                    
                                        let hp=0;
                                        let name="";
                                        let weapns="";


//Adding html literals on the onclick

                  // I think the problem is below here

        container.innerHTML+=
        `<span class="child${numInc} child">
        <div class="numbers"></div>
                <div class="name-display"></div>
                    <input class="name-input">
                    <button class="name-sub-btn">Submit</button>

                    <div class="hp-display"></div>
                    <input class="hp-input">
                    <button class="hp-sub-btn">Submit</button>


                    <div class="weapons-display"></div>
                    <input class="weapons-input">
                    <button class="weapons-sub-btn">Submit</button>
        </span>`
                                            numInc=numInc+1 //
                                    console.log(`child${numInc}`)           
                                empty()
                        
let numbers=document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")
        console.log(numbers)
        for(let i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            console.log(numbers[i])
                for(let i=0;i<numToBeRe.length;i++){
                        console.log(numToBeRe[i])
                            numbers[i].innerText=numToBeRe[i]; 
                    }}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hard to give an answer without example code. Show the basic html mark up and what you have attempted. Edit the question and put the code in there.

Comment: Yes. I will post my code.

Answer (score 1):

**I am sure someone will post a better solution, but for now my wild code:**

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/KKobejZ)

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="test-that-element-is-same" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div data-id="2" />2</div>
  <div data-id="3" />3</div>
  <div data-id="4" />4</div>
</div>



const divs = document.querySelector("#list").children;
const divArray = [].slice.call(divs);

const numericalValues = {};

divArray.forEach((div, index) => {
  numericalValues[`oldIndex${index}`] = {
    oldIndex: index,
    value: parseInt(div.attributes["data-id"].nodeValue)
  };
});

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.value > b.value) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.value < b.value) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

const finalData = Object.values(numericalValues).sort(compare);

const storage = finalData.map((div, index) => {
  return divs[div.oldIndex];
});

document.querySelector("#list").innerHTML = "";

storage.forEach((div) => {
  document.querySelector("#list").appendChild(div);
});
```